# Decoding data from swap event. Uniswap V3

Tags: decoding, uniswapv3

I'm learning how to listen events in blockchain. So I listened an event Swap on Uniswap V3 and got this result:

```
{
  blockNumber: 15560305,
  blockHash: '0x93fc57218eeb84d071e2f2f81d3e410a7e7981c6b53efb73101b4767c8ffe905',
  transactionIndex: 178,
  removed: false,
  address: '0x88e6A0c2dDD26FEEb64F039a2c41296FcB3f5640',
  data: '0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005f5e1000fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff0858f94155405810000000000000000000000000000000000006728d2d3f2cada59e3cbc98513f5000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a8ef31a7a4b0a2530000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000031b77',
  topics: [
    '0xc42079f94a6350d7e6235f29174924f928cc2ac818eb64fed8004e115fbcca67',
    '0x00000000000000000000000068b3465833fb72a70ecdf485e0e4c7bd8665fc45',
    '0x00000000000000000000000068b3465833fb72a70ecdf485e0e4c7bd8665fc45'
  ],
  transactionHash: '0x1980388f4459f1932f2df2f5fe9fd4854eda822deba0f8a7f59fc787f11fab7e',
  logIndex: 321
}
```

As I understand the data like addresses and amounts is encoded in data. So I tried to decode it:

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3();

const typesArray = [
    {type: 'address', name: 'sender'}, 
    {type: 'address', name: 'recipient'},
    {type: 'int256', name: 'amount0'},
    {type: 'int256', name: 'amount1'},
    {type: 'uint160', name: 'sqrtPriceX96'},
    {type: 'uint128', name: 'liquidity'},
    {type: 'int24', name: 'tick'}
];

const data = '0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005f5e1000fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff0858f94155405810000000000000000000000000000000000006728d2d3f2cada59e3cbc98513f5000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a8ef31a7a4b0a2530000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000031b77';

const decodedParameters = web3.eth.abi.decodeParameters(typesArray, data);
```

And I get en error:

```
reason: 'data out-of-bounds',
  code: 'BUFFER_OVERRUN',  length: 160,
  offset: 192
```

Is it the right way to decode it? I only used abiDecoder.decodeMethod() for decoding input data from transactions. So I got confused with different ways of encoding/decoding.

This code gives the same error:

```
const data = '0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005f5e1000fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff0858f94155405810000000000000000000000000000000000006728d2d3f2cada59e3cbc98513f5000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a8ef31a7a4b0a2530000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000031b77';
topics = ["0xc42079f94a6350d7e6235f29174924f928cc2ac818eb64fed8004e115fbcca67","0x00000000000000000000000068b3465833fb72a70ecdf485e0e4c7bd8665fc45","0x00000000000000000000000068b3465833fb72a70ecdf485e0e4c7bd8665fc45"]
const decodedParameters = web3.eth.abi.decodeLog(typesArray, data, topics);
```

Answer (score 2):

So I looked at logs on Etherscan and found my event there.

```
Topics
0 0xc42079f94a6350d7e6235f29174924f928cc2ac818eb64fed8004e115fbcca67
1 0x00000000000000000000000068b3465833fb72a70ecdf485e0e4c7bd8665fc45
2 0x00000000000000000000000068b3465833fb72a70ecdf485e0e4c7bd8665fc45
Data
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005f5e1000
fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff0858f9415540581
0000000000000000000000000000000000006728d2d3f2cada59e3cbc98513f5
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a8ef31a7a4b0a253
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000031b77
```

I decoded the first string from data and found amount0 there. So I understood that this five strings from data are amount0,amount1,sqrtPriceX96,liquidity,tick .
That's why I simply commented first 2 lines of my array:

```
const typesArray = [
    /* {type: 'address', name: 'sender'}, 
    {type: 'address', name: 'recipient'}, */
    {type: 'int256', name: 'amount0'},
    {type: 'int256', name: 'amount1'},
    {type: 'uint160', name: 'sqrtPriceX96'},
    {type: 'uint128', name: 'liquidity'},
    {type: 'int24', name: 'tick'}
];
```

And it worked:

```
{
    "0": "1600000000",
    "1": "-1115327466528569983",
    "2": "2092322563758657713336077772985333",
    "3": "12173002913898078803",
    "4": "203639",
    "__length__": 5,
    "amount0": "1600000000",
    "amount1": "-1115327466528569983",
    "sqrtPriceX96": "2092322563758657713336077772985333",
    "liquidity": "12173002913898078803",
    "tick": "203639"
}
```